# WebGL: Reuse assets when reusing a canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, webgl

I'm writing a small tool which allows developers to render certain 3D content on a canvas using WebGL.

It will be used by specifying a view and camera, like this simplified example:

```
displayView( '#myCanvas1', [0, 5, 2] );
```

which might be called several times to display in several canvases:

```
displayView( '#myFrontCanvas', [0, 5, 2] );
displayView( '#mySideCanvas', [5, 0, 2] );
```

or might be called multiple times on the *same* canvas to change the view:

```
displayView( '#myCanvas', [0, 5, 2] );
// later
displayView( '#myCanvas', [5, 0, 2] );
// later
displayView( '.thisCanvasIsActuallyTheSameOneAgain', [5, 0, 0] );
```

Each time it's called on a new canvas, it will need to set up buffers, shaders, etc. But when called on a previously used canvas, it should re-use the old buffers and shaders. I don't think it's possible to share resources between contexts so I need to duplicate & keep track of them myself.

My thought is to store all the buffers, shaders, etc. in an array each time it is called on a canvas, then search this array in later calls. I can't store the canvas objects in the array because it will mess up garbage collection, so my XY problem is: can I check if a particular shader, program or buffer belongs to a particular context? Also am I correct in my belief that when the canvas is removed, the shaders and buffers will be removed *even though they are still referenced in the array*?

As the title suggests, I'm also open to better solutions to the full problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with most other JavaScript objects, you can add a property to the context object itself, which will stick around as long as the context does. As long as you don't happen to use the same name as someone else, this will work fine, so use a nice unique name.

Something like:

```
function initializeStorage(context) {
    return { ... };
}

function getStorage(context) {
    if (!('_DavesLibraryPrivateStorage' in context)) {
        context._DavesLibraryPrivateStorage = initializeStorage(context);
    }
    return context._DavesLibraryPrivateStorage;
}

context.useProgram(getStorage(context).program);
```

Future versions of JavaScript will likely make it possible to do this in a clean way using *WeakMap* (available now in Firefox and in Chrome behind a flag!) or *private symbols*, so just consider this an interim kludge.

Comment: Really don't know why I didn't think of that. Thanks!